# How to display video without progress bar on safari?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, safari

I'm trying to display a video with the HTML video tag on my website. The problem is that I really have to hide the time progress bar. I tried the below code:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  display: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {
  display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
    display: none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
video::-moz-range-track{
   display: none !important;
}
.IIV::-webkit-media-controls{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 5px;
}
```

And that's my html: (I tried something with php)

```
<video <?php
        $ExactBrowserNameUA=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "safari/") and strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "opr/")==false and strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "chrome/")==false) {
            // SAFARI
            $ExactBrowserNameBR="Safari";
        } else {
            // OUT OF DATA
            $ExactBrowserNameBR="OUT OF DATA";
        };
        if ($ExactBrowserNameBR=="Safari") {
            echo "controls";
        }
         ?> class="videoPub" id="videoPub" alt="Don gratuit">
            <source src=<?php echo '"ads/'.$selectedAd['ID_Ad'].'.mp4"';?> type="video/mp4">
            <source src=<?php echo '"ads/'.$selectedAd['ID_Ad'].'.webm"';?> type="video/webm">
           <br><b> La vidéo ne se charge pas sur votre navigateur :/ </b><br>
            Veuillez essayer avec un autre
        </video>
        <?php
        $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        if ($ExactBrowserNameBR!="Safari"){
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var vid = document.getElementById("videoPub");
            vid.play();
            vid.removeAttribute('controls');
        </script>
        <?php 
        }else{
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
           var vid = document.getElementById("videoPub");
            vid.play();
            </script>
            <?php 
        }
        ?>
```

But it doesn't work on Safari, the progress bar still appears...
Help!!
Thank you for answering.
[EDIT]
What I really want to do is to display a video on safari, without controls, and if possible, with autoplay. The problem is that Safari only allows video with the controls attribute... but I rally want to disable the progress bar.

Comment: how does yout html looks like?

Comment: Or you can try it with javascript https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_controls.asp

Comment: I can't use your solution @Baracuda078 because I want my video to have all the html controls exepted the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you did not have the control-timeline in your css, maybe this will help you to hide the timeline bar. I don't have Safari to test it but in other browser this works.

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Safari really sucks some times. I think it will not help but you can try to add !important behind the display none. What is also possible, but alot more work... hide all the controls and make then self witch html/css and use javascript to activate the clicked buttons

Comment: It is working in chrome, but not in safari